# Bake not the same as render

Tags: rendering, texture-baking

So, I was working on an iridescent metal material in cycles, the render looks great but when I bake it, the texture looks nothing like the render. What am I doing wrong?

[image: render]

Comment: Without knowing your node setup, how you've defined your material, and how you baked everything it is going to be hard to help you. I'm going to blind guess there is some funky normal based trickery involved here. Since most normal based input is dependendent on the view angle/direction it is possible they don't work well while baking since there isn't a traditional camera based single viewpoint in scene space

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

[bake](https://i.gyazo.com/b3afe8d2933dcae0722030c32c15fee1.png)

[Nodes](https://i.gyazo.com/3523e895532f98c4f0e7a2dd3407a3e5.png)